# Profiling Doctrine 2.0 in Codeigniter

Tags: doctrine-orm, profiler, codeigniter-2

What's a good way to profile doctrine queries when Doctrine 2.0 has been integrated into codeigniter?

Using the usual CI profiler does not how the queries executed because it's using Doctrine and not the native, active record.

e.g. when you add this code **$this->output->enable_profiler(TRUE);** it should also show the queries executed.

http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/profiling.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add a profiler in the doctrine package

```
namespace Doctrine\DBAL\Logging;

class Profiler implements SQLLogger
{
    public $start = null;

    private $ci;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->ci =& get_instance();
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function startQuery($sql, array $params = null, array $types = null)
    {
        $this->start = microtime(true);
        $this->ci->db->queries[] = "/* doctrine */ \n".$sql;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function stopQuery()
    {
        $this->ci->db->query_times[] = microtime(true) - $this->start;
    }
}
```

Then load the profiler as a logger in your main doctrine library (doctrine.php for me)

```
$logger = new \Doctrine\DBAL\Logging\Profiler;
$config->setSQLLogger($logger);
```

And the normal profiling will work fine.

Answer (score 0):

Compatible with CodeIgniter..
https://github.com/ahmetkapikiran/CodeIgniter-Doctrine-Profiler